# How to render different api components at same time in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i am having a container where i am rendering 4 components, each components hitting the api. Api response is coming diffrent timing for this 4 components. Because of that one component is loaded fastly and another one taking time. This make the ui to not look good.

Is there any other way to load different components at same time in react.

[image]

Comment: Make the calls in the parent, after all of them are finished set your state and pass the relevant data as props to other components?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Suspense like below:

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";
import { fetchProfileData } from "./fakeApi";

const resource = fetchProfileData();

function ProfilePage() {
  return (
    <Suspense
      fallback={<h1>Loading profile...</h1>}
    >
      <ProfileDetails />
      <Suspense
        fallback={<h1>Loading posts...</h1>}
      >
        <ProfileTimeline />
      </Suspense>
    </Suspense>
  );
}

function ProfileDetails() {
  // Try to read user info, although it might not have loaded yet
  const user = resource.user.read();
  return <h1>{user.name}</h1>;
}

function ProfileTimeline() {
  // Try to read posts, although they might not have loaded yet
  const posts = resource.posts.read();
  return (
    <ul>
      {posts.map(post => (
        <li key={post.id}>{post.text}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById(
  "root"
);
ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement).render(
  <ProfilePage />
);
```

[More detail](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html)